# Getting the names of types and properties of freebase data

Tags: types, properties, freebase

I have the data in the following format for all the entries in freebase:

> /american_football/football_player,"/american_football/football_player/position_s","/american_football/football_player/passing","/american_football/football_player/rushing","/american_football/football_player/receiving","/american_football/football_player/databasefootball_id","/american_football/football_player/football_almanac_id","/american_football/football_player/footballdb_id","/american_football/football_player/games","/american_football/football_player/forty_yard_dash_time"

but when you enter to the page the real name of the types sometimes differs from its id's last part so how can I get their real names not their id's in this?

edit: i actually mean that i want to get the titles of those pages.

Answer (score 0):

A type is just like any other object.  You can find its name using `/type/object/name` (or just `name`).